# Match the data in the database to show correct information

Tags: sql

I have 3 different databases which I want to get information from upon request.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catbreeds` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `information_breed` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `information_breed_seo` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `information_ems` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `information_ipaddress` text NOT NULL,
  `fact_head` text NOT NULL,
  `fact_ears` text NOT NULL,
  `fact_eyes` text NOT NULL,
  `fact_eyecolor` text NOT NULL,
  `fact_body` text NOT NULL,
  `fact_legs` text NOT NULL,
  `fact_paws` text NOT NULL,
  `fact_tail` text NOT NULL,
  `fact_coat` text NOT NULL,
  `fact_extra` text NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_edited` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catbreeds_personality` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `information_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `information_name_seo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `information_ipaddress` text NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_edited` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catbreeds_personality_links` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_breed` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `id_personality` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `information_ipaddress` text NOT NULL,
  `date_linked` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_edited` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)
```

In the source code, I loop the personalities from the `catbreeds_personality` database. Every personality are linked on the website and when I click on each of the links, the list with catbreeds (fetched from the list in the `catbreeds` database) will be sorting the cat breeds after the personalities I have chosen.

---

**Example**

There is 2 cat breeds in the `catbreeds` database; `Burmilla` and `Abessinier`.

The `catbreeds_personality` database has 4 personalities; `Social`, `Playful`, `Active`, and `Curious`.

The `catbreeds_personality_links` database has 3 linked personalities; `Social`, `Playful`, and `Curious`.

On the website, when the visitor clicks on the link for `Cursious` the breed `Burmilla` will show and `Abessinier` will hide. If the personality `Social` and `Playful` are clicked, the breed `Abessinier` will show and the other breed will hide. And so on. I hope you're getting how it all will work.

---

The only problem here is that I don't know how the SQL looks like for this. At the moment my SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM catbreeds AS cb, catbreeds_personality AS cbp, catbreeds_personality_links AS cbpl
WHERE cbp.id = '6'
AND cbpl.id_breed = cb.id
ORDER BY cb.information_breed ASC
```

The SQL query returns 4 results which doesn't even have the ID number 6.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. It's not databases, its _tables_
 2. You don't need Primary Key and Unique at the same time.
 3. From your description it is not clear what is sample and what you want to get. Show exact tables rows and what result you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM catbreeds_personality_links AS cbpl
INNER JOIN catbreeds AS cb ON cbpl.id_breed = cb.id
INNER JOIN catbreeds_personality AS cbp ON cbpl.id_personality = cbp.id
WHERE cbp.id = '6'
ORDER BY cb.information_breed ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

`Select * from catbreeds cb inner join catbreeds_personality_links cbpl on (       cb.id=cbpl.id_breed) inner join catbreeds_personality cbp on (cbpl.id_personality = cbp.id) where cbp.id = '6' order by cb.information_breed asc`